# Why is accessing a command using the full path different than through just the command name?

Tags: node.js, linux, bash

I added node to my path. My understanding is that I'm calling the same command using the following:

```
$ node --version
v10.24.1

$ which node
/usr/local/bin/node

$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v14.17.0
```

My question is why the versions are different?

Comment: On bash you have to use `type`, as in `type node`

Comment: @saki : By applying the full path, you explicitly tell bash where the command is located. By giving the command name, you require bash first to see whether the command is a function or alias, and if it isn't to search the PATH to locate the command. These are completely different mechanisms.

Comment: we need to know the output of `type node` to help set up the system to use the newer version of node - if you want that ([nodejs 10 is EOL after all](https://twitter.com/nodejs/status/1388116425361874945)). perhaps also include *how* you had installed `node`

Answer (score 1):

`which` will check the `PATH`, but in Bash it is not aware of builtins, aliases, or functions. Instead, it is safer to [use `type`instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/29509), which avoids these pitfalls.

In your example, the most likely explanation is that `node`is either an alias or a function. `type node` should give you a clue what gets executed, but apparently it is not the same binary as `/usr/local/bin/node`.

As an alternative, you can enable logging:

```
$ set -x
$ node
```

If it is an alias or function, you should see it in the output.

---

Here is a contrived example to demonstrate the difference between `type` and `which` (executed on Arch Linux):

```
$ node --version
v16.2.0

$ node () { 
  echo "v99.9.9"
}

$ node --version
v99.9.9

$ which node
/usr/bin/node

$ /usr/bin/node --version
v16.2.0

$ type node
node is a function
node () 
{ 
    echo "v99.9.9"
}
```

Comment: in bash, `which` is a separate binary. in other words, bash does not have a builtin `which`. saying it is unaware of builtins in bash sounds rather misleading. kindly consider modifying your answer to include this nuance

Comment: @kevinnls What I meant was "which cd" reports "which: no cd in", while "type cd" is aware of Bash builtins and outputs "cd is a shell builtin". In that sense, I think it is correct to say that which not aware of the builtins in Bash, while "type" (being a Bash builtin itself) is. In the "node" example, it is more a side-note though, as "node" is no Bash builtin. In principle, speaking about builtins could be removed from the answer, but I think it is OK to leave it.

Comment: ah i misunderstood your intent. i feel this sounds more natural to convey what i believe you have in mind? `which will check the PATH, but is not aware of builtins, aliases, or functions in bash.` --- saying "but in Bash" evokes a sense of "bash's `which` does so-and-so." PS: zsh's which (a builtin) is aware of aliases. which is why i mentioned the which in bash being a binary - or external command